# Could not find generator paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Hi I'm new to Ruby on Rails and am trying to use Paperclip. I have installed the gem and can even see that it's in the gem local list.

When I run the command,

```
rails generate Paperclip Class photo
```

I get this:

> /Users/firstlastname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285:
>   warning: circular argument reference - now Could not find generator
>   paperclip.

I've looked everywhere for a solution, but can't find anything. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your generator:

```
rails generate Paperclip Class photo
```

Error:

- Paperclip in capital.
- Class is not a valid model name

Use this:

```
rails generate paperclip model_name attribute_name
```

For example:

```
rails generate paperclip  user avatar
```

In your case if you are further getting errors then try this

Add gem to your Gemfile and perform bundle install :

```
gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'
```

Assuming you have an User model and you want to add a avatar to it, run following command for adding an attachment 'avatar'
to it. This will create a valid migration for you. :)

```
 $ rails g paperclip user avatar
create  db/migrate/20150111070018_add_attachment_avatar_to_users.rb

here user is the model 
avatar is the attribute
```

If you are using a different model then use that instead of user.
example:

```
rails g paperclip employee profile_pic
 #here employee is the model and profile_pic is the attribute
```

Comment: It's still giving me the Could not find generator paperclip.

Comment: exactly that
rails generate paperclip user avatar
should I be in a certain directory when running the command?
running bin/rails generate paperclip user avatar also doesn't work

Comment: Yes, you need to be in your applications root folder when you run the generator command. Please check my updated answer, your 'paperclip' gem needs complete path. and depending on your model + attribute(user-> avatar or employee or profile_pic) you need to write your generator command.

Comment: I think I figured out what's going wrong. After installing the gem, I ran bundle install but it's not putting it in the Gemfile. Even when I run bundle show paperclip, it says that it can't find it.
How do I fix this?

Comment: You are supposed to enter the gem(gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip') in your Gemfile and then run bundle install. 
Please check this link, I have described each bit clearly. 
https://gist.github.com/AjayROR/88623411947b25b52ceb

Answer (score 0):

$ gem install gemrat 
$ gemrat paperclip

https://github.com/DruRly/gemrat

Install gemrat and run the gemrat command